# Expected failure rate given failure at a certain time for exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose that the time until a device fails $X$ follows an exponential distribution, $X \sim \exp(\lambda).$
Now, I understand that the hazard function $h(x)$ is the conditional probability of the failure of the device at or after time $x$, given that it did not fail before time $x$. For the exponential distribution, this is just constant $1/\lambda$.

But what about the other case, that is, given that a device failed at or before time $T$, what is the rate at which it fails after $t,t\le T$?

I think in terms of probability, this is $P(X \ge t| X\le T, t<T)=\frac{e^{- \lambda t} - e^{- \lambda T}}{1-e^{- \lambda T}}$, and then the rate would be $E[X\le t|X \le T]$ ?

Comment: I understand neither of those paragraphs. About the first: The probability (conditional or unconditional) that the device fails at a certain time is $0$. Could you specify more precisely which probability you mean? Or perhaps you mean a density? About the second: What's "deterioration"? And can a device fail again after it's failed? From the formulations in the first paragraph, I would usually have thought that the device fails once and then it's broken.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed it and added what I believe is the math intuition behind my question. Can you please check now?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. The first sentence seems to imply that with probability $1$ the device will fail at some point. But then the conditional probability that it will fail at or after $x$, given that it didn't fail before $x$, is $1$. And about the second paragraph I still have the same questions as before. The first paragraph talks about "the" time until the device fails, represented by a single random variable; there's no indication that the device could fail more than once, or with what probability it might do so, so it's unclear what the second paragraph is referring to.

Comment: Maybe I am not expressing it in the best way, but what I am trying to say, put simply is: given something did not happen yet, we can say something about how fast it's might happen. Now suppose something happened already, can we tell anything about how it happened?

Answer (score 1):

The hazard (rate) function is:
$$h(t)=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{R(t)-R(t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t \cdot R(t)}
= \frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)} $$
where $R(t)=1-F(t)$ is the survival function, i.e. the probability of no failure before time $t$.
So $h(t)$ is the conditional *density* of failure at time $t$ given that it did not fail before time $t$ (rather than the "conditional *probability* of the failure of the device *at or after* time $t$, given that it did not fail before time $t$"). For the exponential distribution $f(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ the hazard rate function is constant and equal to $\lambda$.

I do not think "the other case" is clearly defined. However, if you ask the "rate" at which it fails at time $t$ given that it fails no sooner than $t$ and no later than $T$, this would be:
$$h_T(t) = \frac{f(t)}{F(T) - F(t)}.$$
For the exponential distribution it would be $\lambda / (1 - e^{-(T-t)})$.